# Python: creating a covariance matrix from lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, dataframe

Is there a quickest way to go from the following three lists to a covariance matrix in Python (numpy array)?

```
Fac2 Fac1  VarCovar
   a    a       1.4
   a    b       0.7
   a    c       0.3
   b    a       0.7
   b    b       1.8
   b    c       6.3
   c    a       0.3
   c    b       6.3
   c    c       2.4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the 3x3 matrix easily using Pandas. Create a DataFrame `df` from the above array and pivot on the third column using `pivot_table`.

For example if you have the following dictionary `d` of lists:

```
{'Fac1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
 'Fac2': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
 'VarCovar': [1.4, 0.7, 0.3, 0.7, 1.8, 6.3, 0.3, 6.3, 2.4]}
```

Create the DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

And then:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(rows='Fac1', cols='Fac2', values='VarCovar')
Fac2    a    b    c
Fac1               
a     1.4  0.7  0.3
b     0.7  1.8  6.3
c     0.3  6.3  2.4
```

Using the `values` attribute on the end returns a NumPy array from the table:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(rows='Fac1', cols='Fac2', values='VarCovar').values
array([[ 1.4,  0.7,  0.3],
       [ 0.7,  1.8,  6.3],
       [ 0.3,  6.3,  2.4]])
```

---

If you don't have all pairs, you can proceed in the same way and fill in the missing values with the transposed index pair:

```
>>> d = {'Fac1': ['a', 'b', 'c' , 'b', 'c', 'c'], 
         'Fac2': ['a', 'a', 'a' , 'b', 'b', 'c'], 
         'VarCovar': [1.4, 0.7, 0.3, 1.8, 6.3, 2.4]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> table = df.pivot_table(rows='Fac1', cols='Fac2', values='VarCovar')
>>> table.combine_first(table.T)
Fac2    a    b    c
Fac1               
a     1.4  0.7  0.3
b     0.7  1.8  6.3
c     0.3  6.3  2.4
```

(I took the idea of using `combine_first` from DSM's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27064930/3923281))

Comment: One more question, when i looked at the data there is an issue, I do not have covariance for both a-b and b-a pairs. Instead I have just one pair values as you can see the example belwo:
{'Fac1': ['a', 'b', 'c' , 'b', 'c', 'c'],
 'Fac2': ['a', 'a', 'a' , 'b', 'b', 'c'],
 'VarCovar': [1.4, 0.7, 0.3, 1.8, 6.3,  2.4]}

Any ideas how this can be resolved into covariance matrix

Comment: Brilliant!! That was really helpful, you are a star! Saved me loads of time